# Which would be a realistic model of a lying rope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, friction, string, models

The (badly translated) original text of the problem states:

> An homogeneous rope of length $l$ and mass $m$ lies partially on a flat, horizontal surface (e.g. a table), with a fraction of its length $l_1$ falling out of it, therefore hanging. Let $\mu_s$ be the coefficient of static friction.
>
> Which is the maximum value of $l_1$ before the rope starts sliding?

Now, the problem itself, given *all* the approximations, is very simple.

Which ones would then be the aspects to consider if the aim is to obtain the most realistic model of this situation?
How much are far the results of the approximation (of each approximation) from the "real" ones? What kind of advanced mathematical tools would be used for models like this?

Note: I'm not asking for answers on how to solve this problem (otherwise it would be intelligent to show my efforts and see where my fallacies lie). Instead, I'm interested in the broader, physical modeling, that is beyond the aims of the course I'm taking.

Comment: Hi Davide S.R. A.. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: -1. What difficulties do you have with the modelling of this situation? What models have you considered? What "approximations" do you think might need to be made?

Comment: Thanks Qmechanic, I've read those files. sammy gerbil, I'll do an edit with my ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to achieve with this model. The most complete model would propably be modeling the individual atoms of the rope with the standard model. This of course is far away from any practicality and it is an unnecessary complication for the system at hand.

For more realistic models it mainly depends on your experiment. If your goal is to measure surface effects, then you need to model the surfaces of the rope and the table with an appropriate model. If your rope has a metal core, maybe electromagnetic effects can be important, so you need to include these.

So all in all there is no complete answer, what an appropriate model would be, because it completely depends your experimental conditions and goals. That does not mean though, that this question unnecessary! One of the most important skills to learn in physics is being able to correctly model the system you are interested in, so it is necessary to practice that from the very beginning.

Comment: It is therefore a matter of what you need in the particular case, and then developing custom-built models. Thanks!